# Is there a way to automatic apply the decryption and encryption on some columns on a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, database

this is the scenario I'm trying to figure out.

I have a table named users having the following columns,

```
id
user_name
email      --encrypted
phone      --encrypted
password   --encrypted
created_at
updated_at
```

What I want to achieve is this, suppose if I ran DQL command that is SELECT so it should automatically decrypt the data in those columns like

```
SELECT email FROM users; // this should give the decrypted email value
SELECT * FROM users; // this should give the decrypted email, phone and password value
```

What I want to achieve is this, suppose if I ran DML command that is insert, update so it should automatically encrypt the data and then insert or update in those columns like

```
INSERT INTO users (user_name,email,phone,password) VALUES ('test','test@test.com','1234123412','password'); // this should encrypt email, password, phone before inserting automatically.
```

I could do this from Server side scripting only, but the thing is the application is already created and changing the whole code for the column names will be a very time consuming task.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Passwords should be HASHED and not Encrypted see `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: You can use mutators and accessor in laravel https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Presumably you have considered and ruled out using tablespace encryption. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-tablespace-encryption.html . That's the most transparent way to start encrypting your data. You could create a view of your `users` table with the decryption built in, but you won't be able to UPDATE or INSERT to that view directly. Plus, your VIEW code will show adversaries precisely how to decrypt those columns.

Comment: *if I ran DQL command that is SELECT so it should automatically decrypt the data in those columns* Use SELECT to not a table but a view which decrypts encrypted columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is [eloquent mutators/accessors Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators) and the default Laravel encrypt/decrypt helpers. Will automatically encrypt when saving and return your column unencrypted. the code below for email field for instance will automatically encrypt and decrypt the email column. biggest disadvantage is you can not search by any encrypted column. hope this helps

```
public function setEmailAttribute($value)
{

    $this->attributes['email'] = encrypt($value);
}

public function getEmailAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value !== null) {
        return decrypt($value);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of it, but the old developer didn't use a model for tables, he came from a CI background, and kind of used old models and created scope functions and used the DB facade all over the place. this is the reason I'm going for the Database level encryption decryption where I do not have to modify each code line where this table is being used.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.7 and later support some options for encrypting tablespaces. Here's a good article introducing the options: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/controlling-table-encryption-in-mysql-8-0/

But there is no automatic way to encrypt & decrypt individual columns. The closest thing would require you to write triggers to encrypt on INSERT & UPDATE, and a VIEW to decrypt as you read the data.

Other than that, you need to get to work refactoring the client code. (That's what I would do.)